# How to use a loop or repeat function for calling the next item in a list in netlogo?

Tags: list, loops, netlogo

i want to ask the first item in a list to create an appointment with its doctor. This is only possible when the doctor is available. If the doctor of the first item it not available, i want to ask the next item to make an appointment with its doctor. Is this doctor is also not available, i want to ask the next item etc, until all doctors reached their full capacity, so until they are all not available anymore.
I have a code to ask the next item, but it does not always use the full capacity of the doctors, and it will be a long code when i enter the values manually.

The code is as follows and i want to capture the `i + 1` etc in a loop.

```
repeat (injection-capacity * count doctors) [
  if i <= count patients - 1 [

    ask item i patientslist[
      ifelse (appointment? = true) and ([available?] of my-doctor = true)[
        create-appointment-with my-doctor
        set color black
        set i (i + 1) ]
       [
        ask item (i + 1) patientslist [
          ifelse (appointment? = true) and ([available?] of my-doctor = true) [
            create-appointment-with my-doctor
            set color black ]
          [
            ask item (i + 2) patientslist [
            if (appointment? = true) and ([available?] of my-doctor = true)[
                create-appointment-with my-doctor
                set color black ]]]
      ]]
  ]
  ]]
```

The loop must stop when count appointments = injection-capacity * count doctors.

does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `while` loop. Therefore create a new local variable, eg. `created-appointment?`. While no one has created an appointment, you iterate through the patientslist.

```
  repeat (injection-capacity * count doctors) [
    let i 0
    let created-appointment? False
    while [not created-appointment?] 
    [
      let this_patient item i patientslist
      
      ifelse (appointment? = true) and ([available?] of my-doctor = true) [
        create-appointment-with my-doctor
        set color black
        set created-appointment? True
      ]
      [
        set i i + 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a break condition to the `while` boolean expression, just in case no appointment can be created, `i < length patientslist` or similar.

Comment: Thanks! I already figured it out and programmed it in a similar way. Thanks anyway!